# Is there a way to make api calls and save data to asyncstorage in react native when the app is closed?

Tags: react-native

So is there a way to run background processes(Make an api call and save data using asyncStorage) once the application has been closed. If there is a way how does one go around the 30 seconds timeout imposed by ios .The app is live on both app store and play store

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task#readme)

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import BackgroundTask from 'react-native-background-task'

BackgroundTask.define(() => {
  console.log('Hello from a background task')
  BackgroundTask.finish()
})

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    BackgroundTask.schedule()
  }

  render() {
    return <Text>Hello world</Text>
  }
}
```

Comment: How does one go around the 30 seconds timeout imposed by ios. Incase the api takes longer to respond?

Comment: It manages OS itself. they will not give us timeframe more than 30 seconds.